# Creating two objects that reference each other in a controller method

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an app which allows users to create an account.  This all works fine but I would now like to create a system whereby users are added to groups and have roles scoped to those groups.  Reading a few related questions on SO I have created a new Group schema and created references between that and my User schema:

My User schema looks like:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address'],
    required: 'Please supply an email address'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please supply a name',
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  group: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Group',
    required: 'You must supply a Group'
  }
)}
```

and my Group schema looks like:

```
const GroupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name  : String,
  members: [{
    role: { 
      type: String
    },
    user: { 
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User'
    }
  }],
});
```

I have some middleware which registers and authenticates a user, but essentially the values from the registration form are currently used to create a new user:

```
const user = new User({ email: req.body.email, name: req.body.name });
```

I would like all users to be part of a group (even if only a group of one) and that the first person in the group will be the admin (they will later be able to add others to their group, manage user roles etc).

I'm thinking that when I create a user I will at the same time create the group they are to be a part of and add them to it, but I don't know what the best way to do this is.  Should I have some middleware that creates the group first, then creates the user passing the group_id of the group that was created previously?

It seems that there is probably a much better way to do this but I'm afriad I don't know what it is.  Any help much appreciated.